# How to make a thread to wait until an event occur and continue its process in ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem

Tags: multithreading, winforms, c#-3.0

```
public void CommandTypeProcess(List<XMLIdentifier> list, Command_Do ObjCommand_Do)   
{
    log.Info("[" + DateTime.Now + "]" + ":AddressTypeSplit class to process each unit in different thread");
    var numThreads = 50;
    var toProcess = numThreads;
    var resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    //ObjCommand_Do = ObjGetMsgnumertorAndIMEIno.UnitIEMIMsgnumerator(ObjCommand_Do);
    //ObjCommand_Do.Msgnumerator = ObjCommand_Do.Msgnumerator - 1;
    //ObjCommand_Do.MsgnumeratorStart = ObjCommand_Do.Msgnumerator;
    foreach(string unit in ObjCommand_Do.ListNumberOfunit)
    {         
        if(unit!=Constant.NullValue)
        {
            log.Info("[" + DateTime.Now + "]" + "Thread is started for Unit"+unit);
           ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(delegate(object state)
            {
               // ObjCommandProcessThread.CommandProcessFunction(ObjCommand_Do,CommandPacket, CommandType, AddressUnitNumber,ObjCommand_Do.MsgnumeratorStart,ObjCommand_Do.MsgnumeratorEnd,AddressID);
                ObjUnitDataPacketProcess.InputOutputPacketProcess(ObjCommand_Do, list,unit);
                if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref toProcess) == 0) resetEvent.Set();
            }), null);
            resetEvent.WaitOne();
        }
    }
}
```

In the above method,i use Threadpool.QueueUserWorkItem for each unit.
whenever any new thread starts in the threadpool should wait for an event to occur and if the event occurs it should continue the process.

Comment: Which part is  not working?

Comment: The Above code is working.It creates new thread for each unit that i m passing in InputOutputPacketProcess method.But i want each thread in the threadpool to wait after it starts,for an event to occur and if the event occurs then it should continue the process in the same thread.

Comment: If you start a thread, then you need to wait it for a signal to proceed why can't you start the thread after you receive a signal? Atleast you can save some threads(system resources)...

Comment: Inside the thread.I send packet to that particular unit.In sometime the unit get offline or disconnected in such cases,I dont want to loose the thread.Uisng event I want to check whether the unit is online or connected once again.if so it connected once again then i will continue to send packet to that same unit in the same thread.